# Near identical HTML forms, one posts correct value, the other doesn't

Tags: php, html, forms, undefined-index

Two of my forms on my page welcome.php are as shown:

```
<form action="welcomeforms.php" method="post" name="Food_Calories">
    <h4>.</h4>//spacer
    <input type="text" name="breakfast_calories" value="Calorie Amount" onFocus="this.value=''"><br>
    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
</form>


<form action="welcomeforms.php" method="post" name="Foods">
    <h4>Breakfast</h4>
    <input type="text" name="breakfast" value="Add new breakfast item" onFocus="this.value=''"><br>
    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
    </form>
```

This is the code on welcomeforms.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['breakfast'])){$breakfastitem = $_POST['breakfast'];}
if(isset($_POST['breakfast_calories'])){$breakfastcals = $_POST['breakfast_calories'];}
echo $breakfastitem;
echo $breakfastcals;
```

The forms show up correctly on the webpage, and when I enter the values 'bread' into the breakfast form and '100' into the breakfastcals form, this is what is returned on the webpage:

```
Undefined variable: breakfastitem in C:\wamp\www\welcomeforms.php on line 26
100
```

The forms are basically identical to my eye, so I don't understand why one posts the correct value and the other doesn't post anything. Is there something ridiculous that I've missed?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Use "one" form, not "deux", "due", "two". You're trying to access an element outside the other form at the time of execution of the one being called.

Comment: Only one form is submitting. You'd have to employ JavaScript to submit *n* forms or do what @Fred-ii- said, which is the better answer.

Comment: If only I could cash in on that one, eh *Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: You could likely keep me in a manner to which I am accustomed @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: thanks for all comments, being a newbie @n-dru anwser made the most sense, but after reading his answer I know what you were all trying to tell me!! Thank you anyway

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079088/near-identical-html-forms-one-posts-correct-value-the-other-doesnt?noredirect=1#comment46391462_29079088) went unseen. One minute after the question was posted.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Shall we sing that song again *Sam?* ^

Comment: By the way, `<form>` does not have name attribute, elements do.

Comment: sorry @Fred-ii I didn't understand what you meant by accessing an element outside the other form, and by the time I checked back the alternative answer that made sense had already been posted so I accepted it. Thank you for trying to help anyway, I know it must be frustrating to see silly questions from newbies who barely understand proper coding terms!!

Comment: What I meant by "accessing a form element outside the form" was; when you're executing a submit for one one, the other one doesn't know what the other one is holding; kind of like *"the right hand doesn't know what the left hand is doing"* type of scenario ;-) Let's call it a "scope" issue also, as in "out of scope".

Comment: ahh I see, that makes sense now! I'll have to  be more careful in future, thanks very much for all your help! @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome Lucy. I hope my explanations have helped, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two separate forms and you can submit only one at a time. Combine them into one.

Also instead of `value="Add new breakfast item" onFocus="this.value=''"` just use `placeholder = "Add new breakfast item"` - it will do what you intend to obtain in modern browsers - see the support: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-other-form-attr

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know, but which other reference should I use here?

Comment: thanks very much, I feel very silly for not noticing this myself! Have changed the two forms into one and it works, also thanks for the tip about the placeholders

Answer (score 0):

Because it is submitting only one form at a time, so it is getting only value from one form.